# HTML document won't recognize images folder

Tags: html, image, broken-links, broken-image

I have a webpage which grabs several images from an `images` folder inside my `htdocs` folder, but they always show the broken link icon.

Here is my hierarchy inside my `htdocs` folder:

```
index.html
style
    site.css
scripts
    site.js
images
    testing.png
    ...
```

I don't get that the CSS and Javascript are fine, but the images don't load

Here is some code:

These work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/comic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/comic.css"/>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<img id="img-0" src="images/testing.png"/>
```

Comment: show us code and where is your images folder in this structure??

Comment: Ok, where is the `images` folder?

Comment: Trying some more, i found accessing the image directly doesn't work inside the `images` folder, but putting it inthe root directory does. I don't want to move all 1500 images to the root directory, so i don't know what to do

Comment: Is it a folder permission issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "../" to go back a directory, that's why they are broken.

Comment: My HTML is in the root directory though.

Answer (score 1):

From index.html the link should be: `src='images/.....'`

From css you should use: `url(../images/.....)` to back to root folder before searching for `images` directory

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with the folder directory.
If your situation is so

```
index.html
style
    site.css
scripts
    site.js
images
    img1.png
    img2.png
```

then you have to use this (from index.html):

```
src="images/img1.png"
```

if you have this situation:

```
index.html
style
    site.css
scripts
    site.js
img1.png
img2.png
```

then you have to use this (from index.html):

```
src="img1.png"
```

if you have this situation:

```
    index.html
    style
        site.css
    scripts
        site.js
img1.png
img2.png
```

then you have to use this (from index.html):

```
src="../img1.png"
```

Comment: My situation is the first one. I tried accessing the image directly, but i got a 403 error.

Comment: try to change the permission for the folder and for images